# Can a bootloader or bootstrap program run in a 32bit protected mode?

Tags: assembly, operating-system

When system starts, it runs in 16bit real mode, so that bootloaders are written for 16 bit mode. Can we write bootloaders in 32bit mode?

Any Help would appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, if you first write a small bootloader to bootload your bootloader (I think).

Comment: You can use an existing multiboot capable loader such as `grub`. Also you can use UEFI.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just write a baby bootloader loading the actual bootloader to some point in memory, give the baby bootloader a GDT and jump into Protected Mode.

But i am sure you know that by now ^^

Comment: But after you switch to 32-bit mode, how do you access the disk?  BIOS `int` calls mostly only work in 16-bit mode.  Or do you mean your "actual bootloader" is just a freestanding program, not loading further code?  Or that it should contain drivers for AHCI SATA, IDE, USB-storage, etc?  As suggested in comments, using UEFI would give you an environment for 32 or 64-bit code where there's still firmware-provided interfaces to storage.

Comment: By writing a basic SATA driver or similar :) If someone starts writing bootloaders they might wanna do the real *fun* stuff aswell ^^

Comment: Having to write drivers means it's not a case "**just** write ...", then.  :P